# JSON-LD: Is the name of the value necessary?

Tags: json, schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I'm currently working on adding a structured data of the **web application** in */about-page*. I want to add there a property. In the following code, I'm using both the `name` and `value` (as I saw in the *schema.org*).

**Q:** Do I have to use only `value` without the `name`, and set eg `Modularity` as a `value` and drop the description?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "product",
"name":"Product_name",
"additionalProperty":
    {
    "@type":"propertyValue",
    "name":"Main features",
    "value":
        [
            {
            "@type":"propertyValue",
            "name": "Detailed documentation",
            "value": "description_of_the_documentation"
            },  
            {
            "@type":"propertyValue",
            "name": "Fully responsive",
            "value": "description_of_the_responsiveness"
            }
        ],

    "@type":"propertyValue",
    "name":"Other features",
    "value":
        [
            {
            "@type":"propertyValue",
            "name": "Modularity",
            "value": "description_of_the_modularity"
            },  
            {
            "@type":"propertyValue",
            "name": "Frequent updates",
            "value": "description_of_the_updates"
            }
        ]
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: (1) Note that Schema.org types are case-sensitive. So you have to use `PropertyValue` instead of `propertyValue` etc. (2) You have to use an array for the `additionalProperty` values.

Comment: (1) It is, but if you're using JSON-LD, you may leave the first letter not capital.

Comment: What makes you think that? If you use `"@type":"propertyValue"`, the term URI is `http://schema.org/propertyValue`, which is different from `http://schema.org/PropertyValue` (the latter is a valid Schema.org type, the former not).

Comment: I've tested this on Google Structured Data Testing Tool, and there were no errors. You think it's possible, that google does not report case sensitiveness as an error, but in reality it is? Also in the search console, it is not reported as an error.

Comment: I see - Google’s SDTT seems to ignore such errors for Schema.org. But that doesn’t make it valid, of course. It will also not work for other consumers than Google. It’s easy to see why case matters: When creating your own vocabulary, you could define two types that mean different things, and whose names only differ in case. Consumers *have* to differentiate, otherwise they interpret the data wrongly. -- In the case of Schema.org, types always start with an uppercase letter (and properties with lowercase), so it’s possible for SDTT to ignore errors if they want to, but I wouldn’t rely on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `Boolean` value for the [`value`](http://schema.org/value) property.

```json
{
  "@type": "PropertyValue",
  "name": "Modularity",
  "value": true
}
```

If you want to describe the feature, use the [`description`](http://schema.org/description) property in addition.